# Same Results in Same Machines - Different Results across Different Machines/OS using MATLAB Parallel Environment

Tags: matlab, random, parallel-processing, parfor

I'm pretty sure I'm controlling correctly the Random Number Generator when analyzing my data in my PC. Yet when I put the script to run in another server I get back different results. And the reason I think my code is correct is because I have total reproducability within a machine. Same results in same machines, always! Different results when using the server...

- My PC has Windows and one Intel i7 (4cores), while the server has Linux and one Intel XEON (8cores).

I've read the documentation regarding  parfor really thoroughly, and what I'm doing is to assign a specific Substream number in each iteration, according to the iteration number and **not** the worker id.

Even when trying to create a pool with the same number of workers (4) in the 8core machine, I still get different results...

Here is the basic code used, without the irrelevant details.

```
myCluster = parcluster('local'); myCluster.NumWorkers = 4;
saveProfile(myCluster); parcluster('local')
parpool('local', 4)

spmd
  rng(0,'combRecursive');
end

parfor iter = 1:10
  stream = RandStream.getGlobalStream();
  stream.Substream = (iter);
  ...
  ...
end
```

Comment: Please edit your question and upload your code in plain text format instead of an image of your code.

Comment: sorry, it's my first post, still trying to figure how it works!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to get started. Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure the random numbers are different? How different are your different results?

Comment: Yeap, I'm sure they are different and that they are different enough to not be able to suggest to someone else to run my script and get "the same" results! Statistical significance in experiments is kinda fragile some times...

Comment: That is not the question I asked. The random numbers should be the same on each machine. The difference is likely in the libraries used to make the calculations, which is why it would be very useful for you to provide context on what "different results" actually means.

Comment: You are right, I'll get back to you as soon as I have a more definite answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that this is unique to parfor and running code in parallel?  In general, MATLAB isn't guaranteed to give bit-for-bit identical answers on different operating systems because of different optimizations that the system and 3rd party libraries use across OSes.  Moreover, if the two systems have different processor architectures, it's even less likely you'll get bit-for-bit identical answers because there will be different optimizations for the instruction sets of each processor.

Comment: After trying to breakdown the code as much as I could to pinpoint where do I start having differences I ended up thinking the same thing...

I'm using a hill-climbing method with a lot of calculations with many digits so maybe you are right. I mean that's my only guess till now.